# How to loop rspecs with different expectations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I have three model specs with similar code that expect slightly different numerical outcomes. Instead of nearly duplicating the code three times, I'm trying to do this in a DRY way.

Here's the code:

```
tests = [
  {test_name: "this-year", arrival_date: 2.days.ago,    ytd: 1, ly: 0},
  {test_name: "last-year", arrival_date: 14.months.ago, ytd: 0, ly: 1},
  {test_name: "very old",  arrival_date: 3.years.ago,   ytd: 0, ly: 0},
]

tests.each do |t|
  it "increments #{t[:test_name]} order correctly" do
    expect{
      order = create(:order, buyer: @bs.buyer, seller: @bs.seller, arrival_date: t[:arrival_date])
      @bs.reload
    }.to change{ @bs.orders_count }.from(0).to(1)
    .and change{ @bs.orders_count_ytd }.from(0).to(t[:ytd])
    .and change{ @bs.orders_count_ly }.from(0).to(t[:ly])
  end
end
```

To me, this setup makes a lot of sense - it allows us to easily see the difference between tests and it eliminates redundant code.

However, this throws errors:

```
[Test 1]: expected `@bs.orders_count_ly` to have changed from 0 to 0, but did not change
[Test 2]: expected `@bs.orders_count_ytd` to have changed from 0 to 0, but did not change
[Test 3]: expected `@bs.orders_count_ytd` to have changed from 0 to 0, but did not change
            ...and:
          expected `@bs.orders_count_ly` to have changed from 0 to 0, but did not change
```

The only solutions I'm aware of would involve adding ugly if/then-type statements to change the expectations based on the test, but this seems to make the advantages of this approach (concision and clarity) moot. Is there an elegant way to make this work that respects established patterns?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that RSpec doesn't like `...to change(...).from(0).to(0)`

Maybe purists will say there should only be one expectation per `it` block, but anyway I would do it like this:

```rb
tests = [
  {test_name: "this-year", arrival_date: 2.days.ago,    ytd: 1, ly: 0},
  {test_name: "last-year", arrival_date: 14.months.ago, ytd: 0, ly: 1},
  {test_name: "very old",  arrival_date: 3.years.ago,   ytd: 0, ly: 0},
]

tests.each do |t|
  it "increments #{t[:test_name]} order correctly" do
    bs = create(:order, buyer: @bs.buyer, seller: @bs.seller, arrival_date: t[:arrival_date])
    expect( bs.orders_count ).to eq 1
    expect( bs.orders_count_ytd )to eq t[:ytd]
    expect( bs.orders_count_ly).to eq t[:ly]
  end
end
```

(not sure where `@bs` comes from, but I assume it's in code prior to what you showed)